# JW player. on click getting a window asking open or save file

Tags: asp.net, media-player, jwplayer

I have two applications that play video. in one of them the JWplayer plays the video as it should , and on load, the video plays by itself.Thats what i need exactly
 I'm doing the same process with the second application, but the thing is when it loads the player , first of all i cant see the control bar, second it doesnt play the video. and third when i click the play button. it opens a dialog asking me if i want to open or save the file, but this isnt what i need.all i need is to play the video like in the first application.
Why is it behaving like this ?
thanks all

One more thing, the second application is on a machine that hasnt a media player,
does this have any effect on the player.swf ??? I can see the player and the play button thou. but just wondering ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your iis has the mime type of the video file you are trying to play.

If not add it as follows,

```
     File extension: .mp4
     Mime Type: video/mp4
```

After that restart iis and browse the site again...

**Note**: Search for the exact mime type for the file

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Ok, then run "inetmgr" to go to iis window. which os r u using?

Comment: Hope u've opened the iis window.. If so Go to IIS->sites->default web site(or a seperate website)->your web site. Tnen click on your web site (or the seperate web site you've created) and will find mime type under iis section on the right side. Double click on mime type and will see a list of file extensions along with their mime type. Check whether there is a mime type for your file extension and set one if not. Search and find the exact mime type before adding. Restart iis and try browsing again..

Comment: Is that the file (.swf) u r trying to play?

Comment: No need for a media player at the server side. It just require a flash player at the client machine to play flv,f4v,mp4 etc.. Most of the modern browsers come with flash player plugin. I guess your path to the player.swf and the path to the video file is set correctly in the api(light box,light window etc).